# Alternative to processing files on my app service

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm currently using my app service to process files. I'm uploading Excel files and processing them using PhpSpreadsheet.

Locally, they're going through in less than 90 seconds (laptop, SSD, i7, 16GB RAM). On my app service (small Linux plan), the same file and script, can take upwards of 10 min. This results in the 504 Gateway Timeout error. I then manually confirm data upload in the database.

What would be an alternative to this way of processing files?

**Edit #1**

By Processing, I mean uploading an Excel file, going through the rows, extracting data and updating a database using PhpSpreadsheet. My current file is 102KB, has 4300 rows, 23 columns and takes around 6 minutes. Locally, only a few seconds.

Example:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) 
{
    $file = $this->request->getData()['my_file'];
    $path = TMP.time()."_".$file->getClientFileName();
    $file->moveTo($path);

    $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($path);
    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, false, true, true);

    foreach($sheetData as $sheet_row)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Get a faster server. Use smaller Excel files. But if you really want an answer we need to know what you mean by "processing".

Comment: It also sounds like you might be processing this as part of the web request itself. I’d recommend uploading, adding to a queue, and then process with a CLI in some fashion

Comment: Added Edit #1 explaining what I mean by processing.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Indeed, upload file, if post, load file in memory and process. I could upload it, create an entry in the db and have a cron job go through it maybe?

Comment: Thanks for adding the clarification. Yes, processing in the background could work in this case. You don't really need a cron job, although that would work, you could simply spawn a process after the upload. Then again spawning processes, or even cron jobs, might not be available in the "small Linux plan"?

Comment: It is also possible that your processing is done very inefficiently. But to improve that we would need to see the code. Perhaps it could be a question for: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php)?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yep, not excluding that. However, locally, it's fast and isn't an issue. I also do realize laptop != app service. *shrug*

Comment: you need to use a library to automating task scheduling/background jobs, e.g. : https://github.com/tomaj/hermes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments offer some good thoughts on basic options, summarized briefly:

1. Use a faster server
2. Make your algorithm for parsing your file (whatever it is) faster.

Either may alleviate your problem in the short term. However let's say your algorithm is well-optimized and your server is as fast as you're willing to pay for, both of which may be true for you and are often true in real-world cases. Let's also assume that your file size is somewhat unpredictable, so even when well-optimized and fast, you may need to support outlier cases of larger files that are slow to process.

It sounds like your workflow is (synchronously):

1. Client sends HTTP request to server with Excel file
2. PHP Server runs file parsing
3. Server returns an HTTP 200 (OK) and the parsed file when done. If a request takes > 600 seconds (or whatever the timeout is), it times out and returns a 504.

I would agree with the comments suggesting taking out Step 2 and putting it in [background-job processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs). This would make your workflow look like:

1. Client sends HTTP request to server with Excel file
2. Server sends the Excel file to a background job processor ASYNCHRONOUSLY, starting the processing but not waiting for it to finish.
3. Server returns an HTTP "201 Created" saying the server has started processing the file.
4. Client polls a Job Status endpoint on the server every `n` seconds to check if the job is done

There are a LOT of different ways to do this (the above background processing link details a few Azure-esque ways).

One Azure-centric way I can think of is to use a [function app triggered by a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function). In this case, your server could accept an Excel File, persist it somewhere (or your client could upload it directly to Azure Blob Storage), and then adds an entry to your Queue, saying where your file to be processed is. Using a queue trigger, this can then automatically trigger your function app code, which can pull the oldest message from your queue, go and find the file to be processed, process it in as much time as it takes, and then upload the "processed" file back to blob storage for client consumption.

I know less about PHP background job tooling, hence the Azure-ness of the above suggestions, but there are definitely dozens of other ways to do the same basic workflow proposed above, and the benefit of the above is that you can implement it using basically any language you want, the core architecture remains the same.